# How to convert UTF-8 hex code into HTML (perl)?

Tags: perl

Perl script is handling incoming email containing UTF-8 hex code and is converting it to html.

Example:

```
Input: c=C3=A9d=C3=A9
HTML: c&eacute;d&eacute;
Should be displayed as: cédé
```

I managed this fast:

```
$message_text =~ s/=C3=80/&Agrave;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=81/&Aacute;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=82/&Acirc;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=87/&Ccedil;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=88/&Egrave;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=89/&Eacute;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=8A/&Ecirc;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=8B/&Euml;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=8E/&Icirc;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=8F/&Iuml;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=A0/&agrave;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=A1/&aacute;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=A2/&acirc;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=A7/&ccedil;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=A8/&egrave;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=A9/&eacute;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=AA/&ecirc;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=AB/&euml;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=AE/&icirc;/g;
$message_text =~ s/=C3=AF/&iuml;/g;
```

but this handles only French. I need to handle also Icelandic & Slovak.

Instead of adding similar line for more extended Latin characters, what would be the proper way to handle this for (almost) any language?

Answer (score 4):

> incoming email containing UTF-8 hex code

The format is [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

You should deal with it by using a Perl module designed to parse email messages. [`MIME::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Parser) or [`Email::MIME`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME) for example.

You'd need to use this at a stage before you get the raw data into a string (as your example suggests you have).

That will parse the data into UTF-8. You should then sent the UTF-8 data to the browser. There's no need to try to convert every non-ASCII character into a named character entity: We've had pretty good support for UTF-8 since the turn of the century.